# Animate script and styling issue in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an issue with a jQuery script or maybe its combination with styling, but if you look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mdLtvrpk/3/

Here is my script:

```
   $('.holdingbox').hover(function() {
     var rightbox = $('.rightbox', this);
    var leftbox = $('.leftbox', this);
     if (rightbox.hasClass('active')) {
       rightbox.stop().animate({
         width: '0px',
       }, 500).removeClass('active');
         leftbox.stop().delay(500).animate({
         width: '100%',
         left: '0px'
       }, 1000).removeClass('hover');
     } else {
       rightbox.stop().delay(500).animate({
         width: '80px',
           float:'right'
       }, 500).addClass('active');
         leftbox.stop().animate({
         left: '-90px',
         width: '90%'
       }, 500).addClass('hover');
     }
   });
 })
```

And you can find the css and html through the jsfiddle link, I just figured it would be easier for anyone viewing just to see the code in action altogether.

You'll see that when you hover over each "Shipment Created" notification block, you'll see that it slides over and allows a "button" on the right to appear, but the problem is after the "button" grows past a certain width, it moves beneath the "Shipment Created" block, rather than next to it.

How can I get this to work next to each other, rather than opening a block beneath it?

Comment: As per a note I made recently on one of your prior questions: _When composing your questions Matthew, would you make them a bit less chatty? We prefer succinct questions here. Advance thanks, notes of appreciation, signatures, and various other items (salutations, regards, hopes someone can help, deadlines, etc) tend to be trimmed, and volunteer editors are most grateful if they are not added in the first place_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the widths of your 2 divs, you will find that it works.  In your `else` statement, set the width of the `rightbox` to `19%` and the `leftbox` to `79%`.  You can also remove the position of the `leftbox` ie `left:-90px;`  To make it behave a little better, I also set the `leftbox` width in the `if` statement to `90%`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.holdingbox').hover(function() {
    var rightbox = $('.rightbox', this);
    var leftbox = $('.leftbox', this);
    if (rightbox.hasClass('active')) {
      rightbox.stop().animate({
        width: '0px',
      }, 500).removeClass('active');
      leftbox.stop().delay(500).animate({
        width: '90%',
        left: '0px'
      }, 1000).removeClass('hover');
    } else {
      rightbox.stop().delay(500).animate({
        width: '19%',
        float: 'right'
      }, 500).addClass('active');
      leftbox.stop().animate({
        width: '79%'
      }, 500).addClass('hover');
    }
  });
})
```

```css
ul.menu {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.holdingbox {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.holdingbox .leftbox {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1px;
}

.holdingbox .rightbox {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 42px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 0;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.holdingbox .rightbox .content1 {
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 40px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding-left: 1px;
}

.leftbox.hover {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.rightbox.active {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.rightbox {
  float: right;
}

.holdingbox .rightbox .content1 {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.leftbox.hover {
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
}

//Menu Edit
.menu li a div img {
  margin: auto 10px auto auto;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.menu li a h4 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 45px;
  color: #444444;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu li a p {
  margin: 0 0 0 45px;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #888888;
}

.menu li a h4 small {
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="holdingbox">
    <!-- start message -->
    <!--                    <a href="#">/shipments/i/{'url_string']-->
    <div class="leftbox" style="width: 100%; left: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
      <a href="http://192.168.1.178:8000/notifications/4d798673-fe2e-4294-81dd-49969df0dff6">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <!-- User Image -->
          <img src="/images/clipboard.png" class="img-circle" alt="Shipment">
        </div>
        <!-- Message title and timestamp -->
        <h4>
          Shipment Created
          <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 2 hours ago</small>
        </h4>
        <!-- The message -->
        <p>Pro Number - 214439</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="rightbox" style="width: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
      <div class="content1">Mark Read<br><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/White_X_in_red_background.svg" width="10px" height="10px">
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="holdingbox">
    <!-- start message -->
    <!--                    <a href="#">/shipments/i/{'url_string']-->
    <div class="leftbox" style="width: 100%; left: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
      <a href="http://192.168.1.178:8000/notifications/c7e7add5-eaa2-4b3c-84fe-062322567d5f">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <!-- User Image -->
          <img src="/images/clipboard.png" class="img-circle" alt="Shipment">
        </div>
        <!-- Message title and timestamp -->
        <h4>
          Shipment Created
          <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 2 weeks ago</small>
        </h4>
        <!-- The message -->
        <p>Pro Number - 2102000003</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="rightbox" style="width: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
      <div class="content1">Mark Read<br><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/White_X_in_red_background.svg" width="10px" height="10px">
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="holdingbox">
    <!-- start message -->
    <!--                    <a href="#">/shipments/i/{'url_string']-->
    <div class="leftbox" style="overflow: hidden; width: 100%; left: 0px;">
      <a href="http://192.168.1.178:8000/notifications/1c578226-f735-4d62-be19-7deab4c08dbe">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <!-- User Image -->
          <img src="/images/clipboard.png" class="img-circle" alt="Shipment">
        </div>
        <!-- Message title and timestamp -->
        <h4>
          Shipment Created
          <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 2 weeks ago</small>
        </h4>
        <!-- The message -->
        <p>Pro Number - 2102000002</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="rightbox" style="width: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
      <div class="content1">Mark Read<br><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/White_X_in_red_background.svg" width="10px" height="10px">
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="holdingbox">
    <!-- start message -->
    <!--                    <a href="#">/shipments/i/{'url_string']-->
    <div class="leftbox" style="overflow: hidden; width: 100%; left: 0px;">
      <a href="http://192.168.1.178:8000/notifications/c975030e-64e9-4481-8fd0-0004242515d8">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <!-- User Image -->
          <img src="/images/clipboard.png" class="img-circle" alt="Shipment">
        </div>
        <!-- Message title and timestamp -->
        <h4>
          Shipment Created
          <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 2 weeks ago</small>
        </h4>
        <!-- The message -->
        <p>Pro Number - 2102000001</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="rightbox" style="width: 0px;">
      <div class="content1">Mark Read<br><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/White_X_in_red_background.svg" width="10px" height="10px">
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="holdingbox">
    <!-- start message -->
    <!--                    <a href="#">/shipments/i/{'url_string']-->
    <div class="leftbox" style="overflow: hidden; width: 100%; left: 0px;">
      <a href="http://192.168.1.178:8000/notifications/6721dd8c-4f45-422f-81d0-80fa4fe128f9">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <!-- User Image -->
          <img src="/images/clipboard.png" class="img-circle" alt="Shipment">
        </div>
        <!-- Message title and timestamp -->
        <h4>
          Shipment Created
          <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 3 weeks ago</small>
        </h4>
        <!-- The message -->
        <p>Pro Number - 212222</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="rightbox" style="width: 0px;">
      <div class="content1">Mark Read<br><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/White_X_in_red_background.svg" width="10px" height="10px">
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="holdingbox">
    <!-- start message -->
    <!--                    <a href="#">/shipments/i/{'url_string']-->
    <div class="leftbox">
      <a href="http://192.168.1.178:8000/notifications/48780be4-52af-4278-b67a-6544eda95aae">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <!-- User Image -->
          <img src="/images/clipboard.png" class="img-circle" alt="Shipment">
        </div>
        <!-- Message title and timestamp -->
        <h4>
          Shipment Created
          <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 4 weeks ago</small>
        </h4>
        <!-- The message -->
        <p>Pro Number - 2010</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="rightbox">
      <div class="content1">Mark Read<br><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/White_X_in_red_background.svg" width="10px" height="10px">
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="holdingbox">
    <!-- start message -->
    <!--                    <a href="#">/shipments/i/{'url_string']-->
    <div class="leftbox">
      <a href="http://192.168.1.178:8000/notifications/ca2583eb-5146-471d-b285-5178c35ab0a1">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <!-- User Image -->
          <img src="/images/clipboard.png" class="img-circle" alt="Shipment">
        </div>
        <!-- Message title and timestamp -->
        <h4>
          Shipment Created
          <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 4 weeks ago</small>
        </h4>
        <!-- The message -->
        <p>Pro Number - 210200000</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="rightbox">
      <div class="content1">Mark Read<br><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/White_X_in_red_background.svg" width="10px" height="10px">
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="holdingbox">
    <!-- start message -->
    <!--                    <a href="#">/shipments/i/{'url_string']-->
    <div class="leftbox">
      <a href="http://192.168.1.178:8000/notifications/1e23de34-d699-4e3a-9110-e02ab5ce000b">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <!-- User Image -->
          <img src="/images/clipboard.png" class="img-circle" alt="Shipment">
        </div>
        <!-- Message title and timestamp -->
        <h4>
          Shipment Created
          <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 4 weeks ago</small>
        </h4>
        <!-- The message -->
        <p>Pro Number - 250006</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="rightbox">
      <div class="content1">Mark Read<br><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/White_X_in_red_background.svg" width="10px" height="10px">
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="holdingbox">
    <!-- start message -->
    <!--                    <a href="#">/shipments/i/{'url_string']-->
    <div class="leftbox">
      <a href="http://192.168.1.178:8000/notifications/da74371c-2aa2-45ef-9b5d-28210c3816bb">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <!-- User Image -->
          <img src="/images/clipboard.png" class="img-circle" alt="Shipment">
        </div>
        <!-- Message title and timestamp -->
        <h4>
          Shipment Created
          <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 1 month ago</small>
        </h4>
        <!-- The message -->
        <p>Pro Number - 214050</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="rightbox">
      <div class="content1">Mark Read<br><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/White_X_in_red_background.svg" width="10px" height="10px">
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <!-- end notification -->
</ul>
```

Comment: Okay I'll give that a shot. Out of curiosity, is there anything I can do about the large white spaces in between the left and right when it's hovered? And do you might have any suggestions about fixing that little 'clunk' right after initially hovering over the notification? Thanks for your help too!

Comment: I think that the `float:right` on the `rightbox` is causing some of the issues.  If you set the widths as stated, you should not need to move the `leftbox` `left:-90px`

Comment: Also create a rule for  `ul.menu { list-style-type: none; }`

Comment: to minimize the clunk, set the height of the `holdingbox`  I set it in the code above to be `50px`